# How to allow for multiple sliding boxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

trying to edit this javascript and page so that when I hit one button, two slidouts will occur at one time, with one behind the other sliding out twice as far. Kind of like sliding doors. For instance, if you hit Melbourne, I want two windows to slide out instead of one. You can see where I already butchered the code with the black box and added the redundant javascript. It will be used as a nifty way of displaying form options/navigation, eventually.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to make two slide out at once, though. Here's the code. Any help?

http://jsfiddle.net/justin1390/tL2eo45z/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.w3c a').click(function () {
        var location = $(this).data('location');
        var formSelector = '.crmWebToEntityForm[data-location="' + location + '"]';
        console.log(formSelector);
        var targetForm = $(formSelector);
        var formWasAlreadyVisible = targetForm.is(':visible');

        $('.w3c a').removeClass('selected');
        $(".crmWebToEntityForm:visible").hide().animate({
            right: '-320px'
        });

        if (formWasAlreadyVisible) {
            return;
        }

        $(this).addClass('selected');
        targetForm.show().animate({
            right: '0'
        }, 1300);

    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.w3c a').click(function () {
        var location = $(this).data('location');
        var formSelector = '.crmWebToEntityForm1[data-location="' + location + '"]';
        console.log(formSelector);
        var targetForm = $(formSelector);
        var formWasAlreadyVisible = targetForm.is(':visible');

        $('.w3c a').removeClass('selected');
        $(".crmWebToEntityForm1:visible").hide().animate({
            right: '-320px'
        });

        if (formWasAlreadyVisible) {
            return;
        }

        $(this).addClass('selected');
        targetForm.show().animate({
            right: '0'
        }, 1300);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulty understanding what you're trying to do, but if you want to have two elements sliding, why don't you just create two divs with different background colours? Then on click you can assign them a class to animate them, or animate with jQuery. It would be a simple matter of having one element slide at a slower rate than another to have it trailing behind.

```
//JAVASCRIPT
$('.w3c a').click(function (){
$('#yourElement').addClass('animate');
$('#your2ndElement').addClass('animateSlow');
});

/CSS
#yourElement, #your2ndElement{
position: absolute;
right: 1000px;
}

.animate{
animation: slide 1s linear;
}

.animateSlow{
animation: slide 2s linear;
}

@keyframes slide{
transform: translate(-2000px);
}
```

Don't forget your vendor prefixes on your keyframes!

Comment: That's kind of what I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/justin1390/9txoj102/3/

This is basically exactly what I want.

The question is if that's the most efficient way to do it. Yours looked simple, but I was having trouble controlling how it slid in and out.

Comment: @JustinC I prefer CSS animations, because I usually find the performance to be better than jQuery animations. You might have to do some math or trial/error to figure out exactly how long each box should slide for.